# Sharing a queue between multiple classes on Android

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

Essentially I need a suggestion on a design here - not looking for an actual implementation. I need to create a class that will hold a queue that can be shared between multiple instances of other classes. The queue will hold jobs that need to be executed one by one. The user may add more jobs to the queue at any point. What would be a good approach here?

I know singletons are bad-ish so I'm not rushing to crete one however not really sure what's a good design in that case. Feels like creating a full blown service is a bit of an overkill especially that the queue will be used only to scheduling jobs that can be executed quite fast and the service asks for a lot of resources. I don't care that much if the app gets killed and the queue nullified.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Do you use a dependency injection library like Dagger? In that case I would go for a Singletone scoped object.

Comment: I do not unfortunately - building an sdk so trying to reduce the number of libraries I'm depending on

Comment: Using Dagger might solve the issue, but it is huge overkill. 
By multiple classes you actually mean multiple Activities?

Comment: you dont have to create a full blown service since that one already exists: `IntentService` - "This "work queue processor" pattern is commonly used to offload tasks from an application's main thread."

Comment: @simekadam In some way yes - it's actually more of a queue processing classes that will create tasks and queue them up on the queue that I'm planning to create. However they will provide an interface for for activities to implement for a callback

Comment: @pskink not sure if `IntentService` is a suitable solution here - wouldn't that just create a bunch of services and they'll still need to access a common queue? As in, every time I'm queueing a bunch of objects, IntentService will be created even if the previous one hasn't finished?

Comment: Service is a singleton: no multiple instances exist and IntentSerice has internal queue to hold client's requests

Comment: @pskink that does make sense then - instead of spinning off async tasks I can keep reusing the intent service if it's available, plus it will go away when it's not used. do you want to make your syggestion an answer?

Comment: so if IntentService doesn't match your needs make a normal Service: then you have a full control over it and using the Binder you can directly "talk" to that Service from/to your Activity clients

Comment: @pskink Just to clarify, with the intent service, is it ok to start it multiple times from a loop? So if I have 40 request for example, can I just issues a start intent for each one of those? first one I presume will create the singleton, others will reuse the existing one?

Comment: yes you can do it, but when IntentService finishes serving your 40 requests it will stop itself

Comment: This Article on [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) may answer most of your questions about it.

Comment: Thanks all, read up on IntentService and it seems that if I want to update the UI while my tasks are executing, I should stick to a full service and bind my activity to it